# google apps script: html - form submit, get input values

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, submit, user-input

I'm trying to use a sidebar with a form to get user input. The code is bound to a Google Sheets file.
Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("This should show the values submitted.");
}
```

Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Please fill in the form below.<br><br>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run.processForm(this)">
      First name:
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
      Last name:
      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
      Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press "Submit", the alert opens with the given message and my browser opens to a url which shows a blank page
(https://n-ms22tssp5ubsirhhfqrplmp6jt3yg2zmob5vdaq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?firstname=&lastname=&gender=male).
I'd like the alert to display the values submitted, and I don't want the extra page to open. 
Pretty simple problem, but everything I read seems really over complicated. I just want to know the simplest way to get user input.

Comment: Use the `formObject`? `Logger.log(formObject)` in `processForm`should get you started.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Html form has a default behavior of navigating to the submission link. To prevent that default behavior you can use `event.preventDefault()` function in HTML like so:

```
 <form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this)">
```

**Note**: You can find more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

The form elements are sent as an object in the argument to the processForm function, to view them you can use [`JSON.stringfy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Learn more about objects [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Your processForm function would be modified like so:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(JSON.stringify(formObject))
  // To access individual values, you would do the following
  var firstName = formObject.firstname 
  //based on name ="firstname" in <input type="text" name="firstname">
  // Similarly
  var lastName = formObject.lastname
  var gender = formObject.gender
  ui.alert (firstName+";"+lastName+";"+gender)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for html form, the default submit method is GET, and the submitted form data will be visible in the page address field.

You can try changing the method to POST:

```
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this) method="post"">
```

Refer to this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp#method

Edit: I tried this and realised we still need to add event.preventDefault();